# Incorrect date formatting for MMM in .NET in Unix containers

Tags: docker, .net-core

We're currently running a .NET 6 application in an Alpine container image, and we've noticed new builds have started to have issues with the localization of dates in the en-AU culture, specifically the `MMM` format. Certain months (June, July and September) are being formatted as `June`, `July` and `Sept`.

We've reproduced the issue with the following code:

```cs
Console.WriteLine($"CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = {CultureInfo.CurrentCulture}");
Console.WriteLine($"DateTime.Today = {DateTime.Today}");

var dtf = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat;
var dtfi = DateTimeFormatInfo.GetInstance(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

Console.WriteLine($"AbbreviatedMonthNames = {string.Join(",", dtf.AbbreviatedMonthNames)}");
Console.WriteLine($"AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames = {string.Join(",", dtf.AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames)}");

var property = typeof(DateTimeFormatInfo).GetProperty("FormatFlags", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);

Console.WriteLine($"property.Value = {property.GetValue(dtfi)}");

foreach (var format in new string[] { "dd-MMM-yyyy", "dd-MMMM-yyyy" })
{
    Console.WriteLine($"format = {format} ==> {DateTime.Today.ToString(format)}");
}

for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
{
    var date = new DateTime(2023, i, 1);
    Console.WriteLine($"date = {date}, dd-MMM-yyyy = {date.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")}, dd-MMMM-yyyy = {date.ToString("dd-MMMM-yyyy")}");
}
```

Running on the `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0-alpine` image, it gives the following output:

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = en-AU
DateTime.Today = 5/6/2023 12:00:00am
AbbreviatedMonthNames = Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sept,Oct,Nov,Dec,
AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames = Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,June,July,Aug,Sept,Oct,Nov,Dec,
property.Value = UseGenitiveMonth
format = dd-MMM-yyyy ==> 05-June-2023
format = dd-MMMM-yyyy ==> 05-June-2023
date = 1/1/2023 12:00:00am, dd-MMM-yyyy = 01-Jan-2023, dd-MMMM-yyyy = 01-January-2023
date = 1/2/2023 12:00:00am, dd-MMM-yyyy = 01-Feb-2023, dd-MMMM-yyyy = 01-February-2023
date = 1/3/2023 12:00:00am, dd-MMM-yyyy = 01-Mar-2023, dd-MMMM-yyyy = 01-March-2023
date = 1/4/2023 12:00:00am, dd-MMM-yyyy = 01-Apr-2023, dd-MMMM-yyyy = 01-April-2023
date = 1/5/2023 12:00:00am, dd-MMM-yyyy = 01-May-2023, dd-MMMM-yyyy = 01-May-2023
date = 1/6/2023 12:00:00am, dd-MMM-yyyy = 01-June-2023, dd-MMMM-yyyy = 01-June-2023
date = 1/7/2023 12:00:00am, dd-MMM-yyyy = 01-July-2023, dd-MMMM-yyyy = 01-July-2023
date = 1/8/2023 12:00:00am, dd-MMM-yyyy = 01-Aug-2023, dd-MMMM-yyyy = 01-August-2023
date = 1/9/2023 12:00:00am, dd-MMM-yyyy = 01-Sept-2023, dd-MMMM-yyyy = 01-September-2023
date = 1/10/2023 12:00:00am, dd-MMM-yyyy = 01-Oct-2023, dd-MMMM-yyyy = 01-October-2023
date = 1/11/2023 12:00:00am, dd-MMM-yyyy = 01-Nov-2023, dd-MMMM-yyyy = 01-November-2023
date = 1/12/2023 12:00:00am, dd-MMM-yyyy = 01-Dec-2023, dd-MMMM-yyyy = 01-December-2023
```

Notice the incorrect dates for June, July and September.

We do not have the same issue on Windows, and it seems to happen on all containers that have been build recently. The same behaviour works on older containers.

Any ideas on where to start looking? The code is correct, but .NET is picking up the incorrect formats for the months. From what I can see in the .NET code, if the `AbbreviatedMonthNames` and `AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames` collections are different, the `UseGenitiveMonth` flag gets set, which is causing the incorrect value. But I have no idea where that is getting set, or how to control it. I've read that the `icu` library on Alpine is providing this information, but their GitHub presence is pretty sparse.

I have an example GitHub repo available for those interested (https://github.com/danielbecroft/dotnet-alpine-date-example).